# Protect API from being shared

Tags: api, security, authentication

Our company provides data through a paid API to our customers.

We are currently issuing them with an API key as well as only allowing IPs that are whitelisted to call the API.

This has been working great for us so far however we can't help but think some customers end up sharing our data with other customers without paying for it.

We've been trying to fix this issue and think outside the box without much results.

Anyone has any idea how we could remedy this problem?

Thank you

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

If you mean sharing content that they  have downloaded via your API, you might be out of luck; its non-trivially difficult to distinguish between legitimate (viewing only) vs. illegitimate (downloading/stealing) API access. Once they've downloaded it, there's not much you can do to keep them from sharing it. Watermarks or metadata tagging might help you find it if it is re-hosted somewhere online, but there is no way to tell if a user is sharing the data offline short of installing spyware on their computer.

This might be a problem for your legal team, rather than your development team.